# Modification Tab in opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am working on opencart 3. I have checked that many times working with module I need to clear and refresh modification inside extension in opencart 3. But what modifications exactly do. Can anyone give information for modification tab inside admin in opencart 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.opencart.com/extension/modifications/ you should have googled

Answer (score 0):

The modification cache is a folder where the PHP code that actually runs is stored. It is created when you install an OCMOD extension. OCMOD extensions are a list of changes that should be made to core files in XML format.

Rather than changing the core files though, OCMOD makes a copy of the files and puts them ni to the modifications folder. This is why you must clear this cache whenever you install or remove an extension.